Is there no way to form inverse of a function if it is not one to one?
My teacher told me that for  something to be invertible ,it needs to be one to be one to one as otherwise we wont be able to find its inverse , as there will be 2 values of x for the same y. Is there really no method to find inverse of something that is not one to one(injective)? I really feel like there must be something, it just doesnt feel right when the teacher directly said you cant. Edit- I wanted to further ask if a function can only be invertible if it is one to one,is there something that is not a function so it is not one to one , so we can fund the inverse without it needing to be one to one

How do you define "inverse"?

There are various weakenings of the concept of an inverse function, such as a left inverse (a function $f^{-1}{left}$ so that $f^{-1}{left}(f(x)) = x$) and a right inverse (a function $f^{-1}{right}$ so that $f(f^{-1}{right}(x)) = x$). For example, $f(x) = x^2$ has no inverse, but $\sqrt{x}$ is a right inverse of $f$. Maybe this is what you are searching for.

If a function is not injective, then its inverse does not exist.
That's because of the fundamental property of functions that each value is only mapped to exactly $1$ other value, i.e.
$f(x) = y$ for EXACTLY $1$ $y$.
For example, $\sqrt{x}$  is defined as the positive root of $x$, because, if it mapped to both the positive and negative value, it wouldn't fulfill said property.
Now, let's look at a function that is not injective, i.e.
$f(x) = f(y) = z$ for some $x \neq y$
We can see why this function can't have an inverse by attempting to construct it:
Since $f(x) = z$, you'd need $f^{-1}(z) = x$.
At the same time,
$f(y) = z \implies f^{-1}(z) = y$.
That's where the problem occurs; $f^{-1}$ should be a function, so it may only map to $1$ value. That's not possible in our case, since it would need to map to both $y$ and $x$.

So if it is not a function,it is invertible?If yes than how can we find the inverse and what is the thing that is not a function called?

@Newbie in general, one searches for a function to be the inverse of another function. What is sometimes done though is that one defines a function $g$ to be the "inverse" of $f$, where $g$ maps a value $x$ to ALL values $y$ such that $f(y) = x$. (so the function maps values of $x$ to SETS, not single values)

For example, the "inverse" of $f(x) = x^2$ would be $f^{-1}(x) = { \sqrt{x}, -\sqrt{x} }$.
There's another way to define inverses though, where you limit the domain of $f$ to make it injective. For example, $arcsin$ is only the inverse of $sin(x)$ on the domain $(-\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{2})$

Thanks a lot BobTheThird,my doubt is cleared now

In a theoretical sense, yes.  To have an inverse, a function must be one-to-one and onto.
However, practically, it might be useful to have a limited inverse.  Square root is a good example.  Let's only consider functions from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$.  Square is not onto, it is never negative.  We deal with this by limiting the domain of square root to the non-negatives.  It is not one-to-one either.  We deal with this by choosing the zero or positive value.
Square root is useful but these limitations must be remembered.  Forgetting them is a common cause of mistakes.  Squaring followed by squarerooting might not take you back to where you started.

So if it is not a function,it is invertible?If yes than how can we find the inverse and what is the thing that is not a function called?

If it is not a function then the question does not arise.  For functions, some have an unlimited inverse (e.g. cube), some have a limited inverse (e.g. square), sometimes an inverse would be so limited as to be useless.

Thanks a lot badjohn

I am not so sure what you call one to one. The easiest way to see a function and its inverse is by the mirror image of the function at the line y=x. If you have one y value for two different x, the mirrored function has two y values for one x, an than we do not call it a function. But often one can restrict the definition space and than you have an inverse. $f(x)=x^2$ has no inverse but $f(x)=x^2 for x\ge 0$ has one . Same for $sin(x) for -\pi/2<x<\pi/2$

So if it is not a function,it is invertible?If yes than how can we find the inverse and what is the thing that is not a function called?

maybe you call it a curve, but i don't know, if you treat curves i school. A curve is a mapping of $R$  to $R^2$ like (t,t^2) the "inverse" being (t^2,t)

Thanks a lot trula
